# Running a post deploy ps script or executable

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I am in the process of converting our legacy custom database deployment process with custom built tools into a full fledged SSDT project. So far everything has gone very well. I have composite projects that can deploy a base database as well as projects that deploy sample and test data.

The problem I am having now is finding a solution for running some sort of code that can call a web service to get an activation code and add it to the database as the final step of the process. Can anyone point me to a hook that I might be able to use?

UPDATE: To be clearer I am doing this to make it easier to maintain and deploy our sample and test data to a local machine. We can easily use Jenkins to activate the sites when they are deployed nightly to our official testing environments. I'm just hoping to be able to do this in a single step to replace the homegrown database deploy tool that we use now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my deployment scenario I wrapped database deployment process in some powershell scripts which do necessary prerequisites. For example:

- powershell script is started and then it stops some services
- next it run sqlpackage.exe or preproduced sql deployment scripts
- finally powershell script starts services.

You can pass some parameters from powershell to sql scripts or sqlpackage.exe as sqlcmd variables. So you can call webservice first, then pass activation code as sqlcmd variable and use the variable in postdeployment script.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar. You might be able to do it through some sort of CLR code or maybe an SSIS endpoint, but seems simpler to just do that in PowerShell. I know there are people who've written PS wrappers around SSDT/SQLPackage/DacFX so the next step shouldn't be too bad in PS.

Comment: Yes, this has occurred to me that this would be a possible solution. I was hoping to utilize the "Publish" feature directly in VS but this seems like the next best solution since publish might not do everything that I need.

Answer (score 1):

Particularly if it's the **final** step, I'd be tempted to do this separately, using whatever tool you're using to do the deployment: Powershell scripts, msbuild, TFS, Jenkins, whatever. Presumably there's also a front-end of some description that gets provisioned this way?

SSDT isn't an *eierlegende Wollmilchsau*, it's a set of tools for managing database changes.

I suspect if the final step were "provision a Google App Engine Instance and deploy a Python script", for example, it wouldn't appear to be a natural candidate for inclusion in an SSDT post-deploy script, and I reckon this falls into the same category.

Comment: When I say "deploy" I more mean as a local deploy for developers and testers. who want to test locally. We can use Jenkins to activate the website into our test environments. I was just hoping to be able to do this in a single deploy.

Comment: Probably worth investigating the PowerShell type options then. I would say it's a worthwhile ambition to have the "local" deploy script be the same as the "production" deploy script though, the more times this gets run the better. Alternatively, there are ways of calling a web service from TSQL, but I don't think any of them are a particularly good idea.